# Remote desktop in online ubuntu host

Tags: remote-desktop, tightvncserver

I have  free host at some sites like codeanywhere or codeenvy.

So like to know can i have access to this ubuntu servers by graphic version.

I have tried to install [tightvncserver](https://www.tightvnc.com/) in codeanywhere and by running it i get this error:

```
Wrong type or access mode of /home/ubuntu/.vnc
```

[image]

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

why not using this.. from german site try to ..translate..

```
sudo apt-get install x11vnc  

sudo x11vnc -storepasswd KENNWORT /etc/x11vnc.pass
```

and make it permanent:

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/x11vnc.service
```

containing this:

> [Unit]
>   Description=x11vnc-Server
>
> [Service]
>   ExecStart=/usr/bin/x11vnc -auth guess -forever -localhost -loop -noxdamage -o /var/log/x11vnc.log -rfbauth /etc/x11vnc.pass -rfbport 5900 -shared
>
> [Install]
>   WantedBy=multi-user.target

After you save then exit from the nano text editor, run

```
sudo systemctl enable  x11vnc.service
```

then reboot.

This is from a German site,  https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/VNC/#VNC-Server-bei-jedem-Bootvorgang-starten

Greetings, bernd